# Решение уравнения теплопроводности в конечных разностях дает неадекватные результаты. Что делать?

Tags: математика, численные-методы

Есть две формулы. Каждая из этих формул заполняет числовой массив, причём делает это в несколько итераций. Затем надо значения из этого массива вывести на график.

```
Tnext[i]=(dt/dx)*D*(a[i+1]-a[i])+a[i]; //Здесь всё хорошо и после сотен итераций.
Tnext[i]=(dt/(dx*dx))*D*D*(a[i+1]-2*a[i]+a[i-1])+a[i]; //А вот здесь уже после 2-й итерации все значения превращаются в экспоненциальный вид. Собственно, на график они уже не выводятся.
```

Что с этим делать?

График строится с помощью Qwt.

UPD: Стоп. Я гляжу, эти экспоненциальные значения имеют просто ужасный порядок: +-1,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXe+2XX! От чего же это может случаться?

UPD2. Путём поитерационной проверки удалось выяснить, что все неадекватные значения появляются после 4 итерации.

Comment: Что вы вообще пытаетесь вычислить? Тут все просто. Если формула не работает - значит, нужна другая формула. Но чтобы составить другую формулу, надо знать исходную задачу.

Comment: Ладно, скажу - это уравнение теплопроводности, первая - это формула, данная преподом, вторая - найденная в интернете. А сделать так, чтобы вторая формула работала, никак нельзя?

Comment: Эта формула **не** является уравнением теплопроводности.

Comment: А его решением в конечных разностях является?

Comment: Елки-палки, да запостите уже физическую постановку задачи наконец. Подбираем формулу под неизвестную задачу, гупость дичайшая.

Comment: Дан график распределения температуры по стержню в нач. момент времени. Нужно найти распределение температуры через некоторое время. Для этого надо решить уравнение теплопроводности в конечных разностях. Так конкретнее?

Comment: Это не конкретнее - нет ни граничных условий, ни сведений о материале стержня.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Верхняя формула, та самая, которая работает - неверная.

Теперь про вторую формулу, которая у вас расходится. Попробуйте развернуть эту формулу на 1 шаг. Что у вас получится?

Должно получиться что-то вроде вот этого:

T<sub>next<sup>2</sup></sub>[i] = [(dt/dx<sup>2</sup>)*D<sup>2</sup>]<sup>2</sup> * (*что-то страшное*) + (dt/dx<sup>2</sup>)*D<sup>2</sup> * (a[i+1] - 2*a[i] + a[i-1]) + a[i]

Обратите внимание на величину **(dt/dx<sup>2</sup>)*D<sup>2</sup>**. Этот множитель, как видно, умножается на себя на каждой итерации. Если он больше 1 - формула никак не может сойтись.

D здесь задана. Самое эффективное действие из оставшихся - увеличение dx. Поэтому всегда старайтесь делать сетку как можно крупнее, пока это возможно. Ну а после того как dx тоже зафиксировали, остается только уменьшать dt.

Кстати, в задачах численного интегрирования (а у вас именно такая задача) обычно принято уменьшать dt вдвое автоматически до тех пор пока результаты не перестанут меняться.

PS рассмотрите вариант перехода на алгоритм Рунге-Кутты 4го порядка. Он хоть и сложнее выглядит, но он дает большую точность. Правда, ему тоже надо чтобы (dt/dx<sup>2</sup>)*D<sup>2</sup> было меньше 1 - так что сойтись он расходящейся формуле не поможет.

Comment: Я может чего-то не понимаю, но как метод для обыкновенных диффуров поможет в решении диффура в частных производных? Задача-то баянная, в Патанкаре по косточкам разобрана. И ошибка эта там объяснена.

Comment: @pavel-mayorov Да! Точно! Вот здесь всё это написано: (http://edu.sernam.ru/book_p_math2.php?id=113)

Comment: @gbg, запросто. Если говорить строго - то каррируем функцию **y**, чтобы она была сначала от времени, а потом уже от пространственных координат. Получаем уравнение вида **y`(t) = F(t, y(t))**, где F - некоторый оператор, избавленный от производных по времени. Теперь нам абсолютно ничего не мешает применять к этому уравнению любые методы интегрирования.

Comment: @gbg, если же говорить про реализацию - то просто берем вместо одного числа целый вектор и работаем с ним. Алгоритм от этого не меняется, меняются лишь те подпрограммы, которые он вызывает.

Comment: @PavelMayorov тогда будем называть вещи своими именами - это будет метод Кранка-Николсон. А с нашего студиозуса требуют явную численную схему. Споткнуться он может на граничных условиях (наверняка у него один конец теплоизолирован, а второй - с заданным тепловым потоком) или на соотношении шагов сеток (условие Куранта). Читать ему Патанкара и просвещаться.

Comment: @gbg, он решает однородное уравнение. Разумеется, при "хитрых" граничных условиях наивные методы перестанут работать. Но до тех пор, пока они работают, я не вижу никакого смысла называть именем собственным примитивную комбинацию двух алгоритмов.

Comment: @gbg, какие тепловые потоки? Какая теплоизоляция? Вы о чём? Нам препод даже ту формулу дал, которая первая в посте, выведя её из первой производной, когда там нужна вторая.

Answer (score 3):

Тот факт, что вы видите получаемые значения в экспоненциальном виде, не значит, что их нельзя отобразить на графике. Это значит лишь то, что значения очень маленькие/большие (зависит от знака степени). Предположительно, на графике вы их не видите или потому, что они выходят за пределы вашего верхнего значения координатной оси, или отображаются в 0. Меняйте границы координатных осей или разрешение графика по координатной оси.

Answer (score -1):

Первая формула - схема первого порядка, а вторая - второго, и в ней масштабирущий множитель **dt/dx** должен быть в квадрате, а коэффициент температуропроводности **D** - в первой степени.
Следующий вопрос будет про граничные условия второго рода... Угадал?